# MessageHandler not executing correctly when API endpoint called through Axios.js library

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, axios, fetch

I am currently modifying my client application to use Axios.js instead of Fetch.js HTTP Requests.  I seemed to have wierd behaviour now in my WebAPI Message Handlers while I am making this switch.

I have a custom APIKeyHandler that inherits DelegatingHandler.
I have setup the APIKeyHandler in my application start up, as I want all my requests to the API to goes through this APIKeyHandler.

When I make a call to my API endpoint using Axios library, the requests comes into the APIKeyHandler, however when it reaches the line to call base.SendAsync, it does not await for the response and immediately executes the next line.  I don't experience this behaviour when I make the call to the API using Fetch, VS Code Rest Client, Postman.  I have compared the HttpRequestMessage coming into the handler and it is identical across different callers.

I'm not sure if there is a configuration setting when making the Axios request or if I've done something wrong in my message handler.

```
public class APIKeyHandler : DelegatingHandler
  {
      protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      {
          bool isValidAPIKey = false;
          IEnumerable<string> lsHeaders;

          var checkApiKeyExists = request.Headers.TryGetValues("client_api_key", out lsHeaders);
          if (checkApiKeyExists)
          { //check here the database for the correct combination
              ApiKey clsApiKey = new ApiKey();
              ApiKeyModel aModel;
              aModel = clsApiKey.GetByApiKeyValue(lsHeaders.FirstOrDefault());
              if (aModel.Id > 0)
              {
                  isValidAPIKey = true;
              }
              else
              {
                  isValidAPIKey = false;
              }

          }

          //If the key is not valid, return an http status code.
          if (!isValidAPIKey)
              return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

          //Allow the request to process further down the pipeline

          var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

          //Return the response back up the chain
          return response;
      }

  }
```

Client side using Axios

```
function AxiosTest(axiosparams) {

    return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: axiosparams.URL,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'client_api_key': clientApiKey
        },
        crossDomain: true, 
        responseType: 'json' 
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        return error;
    });
}
```

Client side using Fetch

```
function FetchData(fetchparams) {

    var options = new Object();
    var myHeader = new Headers();
    myHeader.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    myHeader.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    myHeader.append('client_api_key', clientApiKey);
    options.method = 'get';
    options.headers = myHeader;

    return fetch(fetchparams.url, options)
        .then(JSONResponse)
        .then(function (data) {
           return data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return error;
        });
    }
}
```

Adding the network output from the browser
[Network Tab Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL4QB.png)

Comment: I find this particularly interesting: `it does not await for the response and immediately executes the next line`. What is the value of the `response` variable then? It does not hit the controllers anymore?

Comment: response returns 404.  My controller endpoints do not seem to be hit at all.  Now I recently upgraded my API framework from 4.5 to 4.6.1 because a class library from another developer was added to this project.

Comment: Can you also post the request of those 2 API clients using a tool like Fiddler?  (Or, if you are using Chrome,  show us the details of those two requests by looking at the F12>Network tab)

Comment: Added.  I reviewed the Headers, Response Headers and Request Headers tabs and they are identical.  With exception to the fetch call adding the Content-Type header, where as the Axios call did not have it, even though I've added it in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Add `data: {}` in your Axios request.

You can see in this [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86) on GitHub that Axios removes your `Content-Type` if you do not supply the `data` property.

There is a high change that this will solve your problem (I do not know exactly what other filters/settings you have in your application).

Comment: I just figured it out.  I had a spelling mistake in my URL.  Sorry for wasting your time...